# Automate SQL Queries with a Config File

Tags: microsoft-excel, sql-server

I am trying to generate a weekly list of reports, each in the form of a folder containing multiple excel files that use SQL queries. Is there a way to have a "config" file of some sort to input the SQL server address and port, dates, and other relevant data that are constant between the same files of a folder -but not necessarily between files of different folders- without having to manually change each of the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

In the same folder I placed a file named "config.txt" and also the workbook this macro is run from.

The config file contents:

[image]

You can use this macro to extract information from it:

```vba
Sub readConfig()
    Dim configPath As String
    
    '"build a path for a file named "config.txt" located in the same folder as current workbook"
    configPath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & "config.txt"
    
    '"attempts to open file above, if config file is not found, go to error handling"
    On Error GoTo fileErrorHandler
        Open configPath For Input As #1
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    Dim serverName As String, login As String, password As String
    
    While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, configLine
        Dim flag As String, value As String
        
        '"split line of config file to flag and value, assign value to a variable based on it's flag, if the split fails, go to error handling"
        On Error GoTo splitErrorHandler
            flag = Split(configLine, "=")(0)
            value = Split(configLine, "=")(1)
        On Error GoTo 0
        Select Case flag
            Case "server_name"
                serverName = value
            Case "login"
                login = value
            Case "password"
                password = value
        End Select
    Wend
    Close #1
    
    Debug.Print "server name is: " & serverName
    Debug.Print "login is name is: " & login
    Debug.Print "password is: " & password
    
    Exit Sub
fileErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "config file does not exist"
    Exit Sub
splitErrorHandler:
    Close #1
    MsgBox "unexpected string in config file"
    Exit Sub
End Sub
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, this indeed helps!